# Display one image (of unknown dimensions) centered (vertically and horizontally) on the page

Tags: html, css, layout, vertical-alignment

How do I center a single image vertically and horizontally without knowing its dimensions ahead of time?

Also, if the image is larger than the view-port, it should re-size to fit

Is there any way to accomplish all of this without using Javascript?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a page I made earlier doing just this :)

http://kt80.net/

This is the whole code:

```
body{background:#e5e7e6 url(egyptrabbit.jpg) no-repeat fixed 50% 50%}
```

EDIT: Ah, just saw the resize to fit part. You can use the CSS3 attribute "contain" on the background image to make sure it's always within the window, but this will stretch it if the window is bigger.

Comment: this is also a good solution, what you choose depends what you want to do with the image (this works if you only need to center a single image, or if you want text on top, my example works better if you want multiple images in a row or if you need to turn the image into a link)

Comment: this is amazing! (where exactly would I add the `contain` attribute to get resize to fit working?)

Comment: background-size: contain; -moz-background-size: contain;

Answer (score 5):

You can only vertical align if the containing element is of `display: table-cell`, so set that, and then you can use `vertical-align` and `text-align`. Here is an example:

```
​<div style="width: 500px; height: 300px; border: 1px red solid; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center">
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png">
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8Aq5Y/

It does not work if you do not change the `display`, or if the `display` is set to something like `block` or `inline`.

To make sure it fits in the containing element, just use `max-width` and `max-height`:

```
<div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 1px red solid; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center">
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" style="max-width: 100px; max-height: 100px;">
</div>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8Aq5Y/3/